# Linear Gradient Background disappears when printing a CSS object with a linear gradient and a border

Tags: css, google-chrome, printing, background, border

If you try to print the following page using chrome, you will get a black background. The background can be printed if you delete the border. Please make the test. 
Is it a Bug in Chrome ?

```
<style>
#div1{
  width:340px;height:150px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  background:linear-gradient(#fff,#0cf);
}
</style>
<div id=div1>
  Something
</div>
```

Thnks

Comment: have you tried:     background-image:linear-gradient(#fff,#0cf);

Comment: Yes, I tried also this syntax: background: -webkit-linear-gradient( bottom, #fff,#0cf);

Comment: did you have the same result as me ?

Comment: Cannot reproduce in Chrome 42.0.2311.50 beta-m (64-bit) on W7

Comment: my chrome version is: Version 41.0.2272.101 m  (32 bit -  Win XP)

Comment: I have found this listed as a regression bug on Chromium: Good Build {41.0.2264.0   Base Position:  309803} Bad Build {41.0.2272.0   Base Position:  310958}
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=467671

Which likely explains a) that the problem is known to exist and b) that @Paulie_D is not seeing it because it's been fixed on the beta build (and still existent on the release build)

Answer (score 4):

I have also faced the same issue, but realized that it was not css problem.
It could be problem with print option.
Enable "Background Graphics" in print screen.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe I am also having the same problem.  Print Preview and Print output from Chrome 41.0.2272.101m appears thus:

[image: Print Output from Chrome v41.0.2272.101m (screencapture)]

While Firefox prints correctly (though not attractively)
[image: Firefox 32.0.2 (crop from Acrobat Distiller PDF output)]

That region consists of a gradient fill

```
.greenRedGradient
{
    background: #00aa00; /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #00aa00 0%, #ffff00 50%, #ff0000 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#00aa00), color-stop(50%,#ffff00), color-stop(100%,#ff0000)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #00aa00 0%,#ffff00 50%,#ff0000 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  #00aa00 0%,#ffff00 50%,#ff0000 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  #00aa00 0%,#ffff00 50%,#ff0000 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  #00aa00 0%,#ffff00 50%,#ff0000 100%); /* W3C */
    padding:3px;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00aa00', endColorstr='#ff0000',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-8 */
}
```

Surrounded by a rounded corner border on the bottom/sides

```
.areaGroup > footer > div:last-child {
    width:66%; overflow:hidden; border:2px solid black; border-top:0; padding:0 4px; padding-top:2px;
    webkit-bottom-left-border-radius: 8px; -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 8px; border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
    webkit-bottom-right-border-radius: 8px; -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 8px; border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
}
```

The offending div in question:

```
<div class="greenRedGradient">
    <img src="/img/FeedbackFormArrows-Strength.png" style="float:left;" alt="Feedback form arrow indicating strength"/>
    <div style="margin-left:94px;">
        <img src="/img/FeedbackFormArrows-NeedsAttention.png" style="float:right;" alt="Feedback form arrow indicating need of attention">
        <div style="background:url(/img/FeedbackFormArrows-Dash.png) repeat-x; height:32px; margin-right:145px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can comment out the three PNGs (transparent backgrounds) for the Strength <, the ---dashes---, and the > Needs Attention, and it makes no difference in how Chrome prints the gradient.

I don't think it makes a difference, but preemptively expecting the question, the 6 color regions vertically above the misprinting region are done so with 20% Alpha transparency using RBGA CSS codes as follows, and as shown, they print correctly:

```
.r21{ background: rgba( 031, 183, 000, 0.20 ); }
.r22{ background: rgba( 127, 228, 000, 0.20 ); }
.r23{ background: rgba( 224, 255, 000, 0.20 ); }
.r24{ background: rgba( 255, 230, 000, 0.20 ); }
.r25{ background: rgba( 255, 134, 000, 0.20 ); }
.r26{ background: rgba( 255, 033, 000, 0.20 ); }
```

I -believe- this is a recent issue and that it used to print correctly, but I cannot say at all for certain, so I don't consider it relevant/trustworthy information.

Comment: Thank you Thistledowne. 

In your example, I don't know where are you using the class r21 to r26.

My example is very simple. It shows that the problem appears only when i add the border.

Answer (score 0):

Version M42 of Chrome is out of beta and pushed so this regression error should no longer exist if users' browsers are up-to-date.